# how to redirect everysubdomain to main domain? like anysubdomain.domain to domain in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is that possible, if yes then how?

When I write `anything.abc.com/?p=37` must redirect to `abc.com/?p=37`.

I want to do it in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the write permissions from your .htaccess file because WordPress is notorious for overwriting them. In .htaccess in your public_html root directory, add the following lines of code. Before you do this though, change the site url in **settings >> general**.

```
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

You can read more on BlueHosts website: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347

Comment: Thanks ham-sandwich, i want to do it for randomly created subdomains, will it work for that as well?

Comment: Hey @AayQue - yes it will, but you will need to explicitly define them in the `.htaccess` file. For example `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/random/ `

Answer (score -1):

In your Wordpress settings > general settings, just change the site address URL to whatever you want.

Comment: Nope. That won't work! In fact, the whole site will stop working :S